# Facebook like button for a Facebook feed item

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph, like

Here is what I do:

When the admin of a website i'm creating adds a new 'news' item to his website, it directly posts the same item on the Facebook 'fanpage' of the website. This is done by an Facebook app with the permissions to post an item on the Facebook fanpage. So far so good. I'm getting the new post id from the facebook graph.

Here is what I want to achieve:
I'm adding a 'like' button on the original website, but when this is clicked it should be referenced to the same post item on the facebook page. So if someone likes the news post on the website he should also like the referencing facebook feed post. Which is exactly the same.

Can this be done?

I've been playing around with the href etc of the like button, without any success. When I hit the like button it likes the url given, but is doesn't recognizes that this is a feed post.

Any idea?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Facebook may not allow users to 'like' a post on Facebook from another website.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Social Plugin - Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) you can't tell it to like a direct facebook object (update, comment etc.) For this you will need to use the [Facebook Graph API for Posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

Furthermore, you would need to create an new Facebook Application, visitors then would need to accept your applications permissions to their facebook profile and then programatically you could probably setup what your looking for.

Facebook works on "objects", and when you create a news post on facebook, that post has an object_id and has type of "post", but when you offer a url to the Social Plugin Like Button, you're actually creating a new object for that page url - not for the content on that page.

Hope that helps!